# Which Mongoose Traveller 1e books are mechanically compatible with 2e, if any?

Tags: edition-comparison, mongoose-traveller-2, mongoose-traveller

Are any of the books from Mongoose Traveller 1st edition mechanically compatible with 2nd edition?

The kind of compatibility I am thinking of means that I should be able to use rules or stats presented in a 1e book in a 2e game, ideally without changes. I would also call a book compatible if there were simple rules one could apply to make the system work.

If yes, which books are compatible?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "compatible"? In the comments of the existing answer, there seems to be some disagreement about what you are looking for.

Comment: I was looking for books that was compatible system wise. In my mind compatibility means that I should be able to use rules or stats presented in one 1e book with a 2e game ideally without changes. I would also call a book compatible if there were simple rules one could apply to make the system work.

Comment: If you have a specific definition of “compatible” in mind it really should be described as part of the question.

Comment: Sorry. It did not occur to me that it was possible to interpret compatibility between two versions of a game in any other way than system compatibility. But I see now that it indeed was possible to misunderstand it.

Comment: I would be happy to try and tighten my response if you could define more precisely. For example, it sounds - and from what I've seen - that you can use characters from 1e in 2e, with just a slight change where Skills have collapsed into one. That isn't compatible if you mean, "the same"; it is if you mean "a light touch and clean up to bring one in order with the other." Certainly, none of the changes I have seen or read about suggest a change so drastic as to go against my own definition of "compatible", which is clearly different to Thunderforge and yourself, Marius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, none and all of them. None remain 100% compatible; all remain broadly usable.

There are a lot of books released for Mongoose Traveller 1st edition (MT1e), so I couldn't put together a list as requested solely because it would have to be pain-stakingly researched to give you an accurate answer.

Right from the start of the open 'playtest' last year, [Matt Sprange noted on the Mongoose Forums](http://forum.mongoosepublishing.com/viewtopic.php?f=89&t=112424&sid=1f378e0ba5ba038b2b724eb022f528fe#p880703) that while the core principles of the old system would remain, the design team would not let any of the old material hold them back from making changes. If a change would make the game better, they'd make it - backward compatability be damned.

On the other hand, they were not setting out to intentionally invaidate any of the old material - and if you own one or more books from MT1e - or, indeed, other versions - you will not find them rendered worthless. You will need to do some legwork understanding the changes and deciding what to keep and what to go with.

Broadly speaking, the stats for people and places have remained the same. The crunch for ships and ship weapons got a bit of a tweak as did the system for large scale battles. World building has remained the same as MT1e; character creation, especially skills, has undergone some slight adjustment.

As I say, you will find the old books generally usable - but Mongoose did not hold back from making changes in MT2e to 'make it better'.

Comment: While this is a nice description of the design process, it just raises more questions. If they aren't 100% compatible, what parts *are* compatible? What sort of "legwork understanding the changes" has to be done to use a 1e book in 2e? I'm downvoting this answer until these issues are addressed.

Comment: As mentioned, this asks questions that would require an intimate knowledge of each supplement and adventure to answer. Traveller MT2e is compatible with any other version of Traveller that follows the same common ancestry, in the same way that Call of Cthulhu 7e is compatible with all previous versions, as they share the same common ancestry.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Call of Cthulhu, so I have no idea how that works. But supplements for D&D 3.x, 4e, and 5e all share a common ancestry with 1e, but that doesn't mean that they are compatible. If Traveller supplements are or are not compatible to some degree, I'd like to know what that means.

Comment: I think I'll step back, as I beg to differ on your comment "supplements for D&D 3.x, 4e, and 5e all share a common ancestry with 1e, but that doesn't mean that they are compatible." I think they're absolutely compatible, because of the common use of terms and general systems for character generation. Yes, the likes of Feats, templates, Prestige Classes and so forth tweak the way you create characters and skills have become something more than they used to - but I could easily run a 1e adventure with the 5e ruleset. Traveler MT2e is close enough to MT1e to intelligently interchange materials.

Comment: I think that there may be some confusion over what the term "compatible" means. I am thinking of it as "can take something from one edition and, with small adjustments, use in a new edition". This [is not possible for D&D 4e to 5e](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64622/7373). I've added a comment to the question asking the OP to clarify what they mean by compatibility.

Comment: My intention when asking the questions is as Thunderforge suggest in his comment. Compatibility as in: "can take something from one edition and, with small adjustments, use in a new edition"

Comment: -1 This answer does not actually answer the question in a useful way; It merely asserts that there is an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm saying what Mongoose have - that 2e is 1e with improvements. So, 1e is compatible with 2e, but be prepared to make adjustments. The only way to answer this question exactly - with library-like efficiency - is to have owned and read every single 1e supplement and highlighted the inconsistencies with 2e. I doubt that person will be posting here anytime soon.

Comment: I think this is a great answer. I myself have found small differences between the versions.