# What are the major differences between Mongoose Traveller 1st and 2nd Edition?

Tags: edition-comparison, mongoose-traveller-2, mongoose-traveller

In early 2016, a new edition of *Traveller* by Mongoose was released (referred to by some as *Mongoose Traveller 2nd Edition*). What are the major rule and setting differences between this version and the 1st edition released in 2008?

---

Related: [Which Mongoose Traveller 1e books are mechanically compatible with 2e, if any?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76708/7373)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have never played any **Traveller**, however I have found an [RPG.net review](https://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/16/16668.phtml), on which I base my answer.

- **Size:** 2nd edition has 60 more pages.
- **The art:** 1st edition was made in 80s style. 2nd looks more modern, with a great layout and adequate art. There are lots of illustrations.
- **The base system:** Now includes both positive and negative modifiers. Opponents skill levels/defense values subtracted from the one roll. Opposed rolls are kept to a minimum. The target number for success can range from 4 to whatever.
- **New mechanic (Bane/Boon):** you roll 1 more die, and drop either the highest or lowest roll before determining total
- **"Academies"**  It gives you a lot more control over your first term as you get to select skills rather than roll randomly. If you graduate, it guarantees your entry in your career of choice.
- **Jack of all Trades:** The skill that can be gained ONLY during character creation.
- **Skills:** They have been grouped into specializations to remove skill bloat. There is also a nice description under every speciality.
- **Dual wielding available**
- **Encounters & Dangers:** Whole section has been improved and detailed.
- **Equipment:** Needed explanations have been added. Armour have been optimized. Their values and costs now make sense. Augments, that boost your abilities have been added. Communication and Computers/Computer software section has been updated and clarified.Weapon section has been upgraded.
- **Vehicles:** Are described by traits and hull values. There are Speed-bands for the vehicle speed. Lots of new rules have been added.
- **Spacecraft operations and combat** They have taken a new, better approach.
- **Psionics:** Has been revised and detailed more clearly. It has also become more helpful.
- **Trading:** You can no longer sell for 400% of base price, it is limited to 200% now.